# Error highlighting - Visual Studio Express 2010 (C++)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

have been using Visual Studio Express 2010 (C++) well and fine for a good while now, but all of a sudden the error highlighting seems to have turned itself off when editing any file other than main.cpp

I've checked my settings and as far as I can tell they're fine - everything enabled in IntellSence etc.
Have restarted my machine a couple of times
Have completely re-installed VS.
Have checked it in another project so I don't think it's a prject specific problem.

This seems pretty weird to me. Does anone have any idea what might be going on?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced, and check "Underline errors in the editor" and "Show live semantic errors".

Comment: Hi - yeah I've tried something akin to that - I don't have a simple checkbox that sdays "Underline..." but rather I have something called IntelliSense that seems to be handling the highlting - and that's all set to go.  As I said, it works a bit, but only when editing main.cpp.  Weird...

Comment: this option does not exists for C/C++ on VS10

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to your solution/project directory and delete the .sdf file.
3. Open your solution/project again and it will start parsing the included header files again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the answer posted here helped me.

if your project is under some source control (mine was under ClearCase), this solution might work for you.

You need to make sure that .sln , .suo and .vcxproj.user are editable.

Intellisense need these files to be editable else it will not work.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this just happens, I assume because of some code that the Intellisense compiler chokes on. A trip to Project > Rescan Solution will fix it, at least until the next time...

Comment: Nah - still not working.  I've noticed now that it also works on header files - so just no .cpp files (other than main.cpp).  This is weird... I have so been spoiled by error highlighting....

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the error highlighting occurred in VS2010 out of the blue on a header file, but which the project compiled and built fine.  I did the Project->Rescan and all of the erroneous error hightlights (code with underlined red) disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->c/c++->General-> uncheck "Word wrap" (under settings)
Could solve the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this  file that may have been accidentally added in c/c++ code:

**#include< dbdao.h >**

hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 projects in one solution and the intellisence only worked in one project. The intellisence started working only after i commented a specific line in of code  in my project. it was a complex get function.